# How can I remove the main description text box in a Woocommerce product editor page? I only use the "Product short description" text box

Tags: functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

The main description text box which shows up right below the Woocommerce product title seems to not be able to be disabled within the Screen Options dropdown menu. It also can't be moved around, minimized, and I can't seem to find a Woocommerce hook to disable it.

I'm only interested in having the Product Short Description text box show up since my client doesn't use the main description box.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14697220/2757809

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but something like this should work:

```
function wpse70000_add_author_metabox_to_cpt_book( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ('product' === $post_type ){
        unset($args['editor'] ); // set the 'supports' array
    }    
return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse70000_add_author_metabox_to_cpt_book', 10, 2 );
```